# Почему объект двигается не в сторону лицевой стороны а строго по осям? как исправить

Tags: c#, c, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть куб ,задал движение через input.getkey всё хорошо,решил сделать поворот объекта камерой,вместе с мышью всё ,тоже получилось,но когда поворачивается объект оси по которым он двигается при нажатии остаются теми же ,т.е нажал 'W' движение впреёд т.е forward ,но если повернуть куб ,этот же 'W' продолжить двигать куб по оси а не в сторону которую повёрнут куб.

Самый простой код ,подскажите как исправить.

```
public GameObject playerOBJ;
public Camera cam;
public float camspeed = 0.45f;
public float speed = 5f;
public void Move(GameObject obj)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime)*speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime) * -speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime) * speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime) * -speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime) * speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        obj.transform.position += (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime) * -speed;
    }
}
public void MouseCamera(Camera cm,GameObject obj)
{
    float mouseX=Input.mousePosition.x;
    cm.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,mouseX*camspeed,0);
    obj.transform.rotation = cm.transform.rotation;
}
void Start()
{
   
}

void Update()
{
    MouseCamera(cam, playerOBJ);
    Move(playerOBJ);

}
```

Comment: Всё ясно,и понятно вопрос не сложный мне нужна помощь с реализацией.

Comment: потому что задате вектор дивжения в глобальном базисе а не в связаной системе координат.

Comment: то есть использовать local position а не position?

Comment: и поворот. Базис у ССК другой. ССК можно определить как новое начало координат привязанное к объекту и  поворт - либо как начало координат и тройку новых базисных векторов (если они единичные, то они определяют матрицу вращения)

Answer (score 0):

`Vector3.forward/back/up/righ` и т. д. подразумевает глобальную систему координат.
Вместо `Vector3` стоит писать `obj.transform`.

Например,

```
obj.transform.position += obj.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```